# How can I convert dictionary to dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this.

[image]

The inside of dictionary is ... [image]

When I clicked the {top:'Dataframe',rising:'Dataframe'}, i accessed to  two different Dataframes which are top and rising.
[image]

My question is that How can i access these dataframes directly?

I tried to use dict to dataframe examples. They did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code as text not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary access operator `[]` twice

```
related_queries_dict['Big Data']['rising']
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. I think completely different.